# How can I decrypt a string if I encrypt it with a random key

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am trying to develop an android app in java which needs encryption. Also I want to use AES-256 for encryption. But when I look a tutorial of it, It always generates a random key. My question is: How can I decrypt a string if I encrypt it with a random key? Also I tried almost every code in web, but none of them worked, so can you provide a AES-256 encryption code with no salt and IV. If I know something wrong, please correct me and teach me the truth.

EDIT: I am trying to make a password manager app. App has two passwords, first one is the master password that we use for encryption string data. Second one is the passwords that we want to manage. Master password is stored in users mind. And other password will be stored in the app with encrypted version.
When user wants to see his passwords he will input his master key to decrypt the encrypted passwords. So how can I do it? And user's master password will be 32 or 64 digit and I don't think we need to generate a random key. Can you show me some way? I am not native english speaker, sorry for my bad english. Thanks for help.

Comment: Encryption is easy – key management is hard. Encryption will be useless if you are not able to manage the key secure. How to do it depends on what you want to achieve. *"app ... which needs encryption"* is too general. Provide a better description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: *"I tried almost every code in web, but none of them worked"*: This approach may work for user interfaces. But for security, it's a recipe for disaster. Please educate yourself about fundamental security concepts.

Comment: What EXACTLY are you trying to do?  Are you just trying to encrypt a simple message and store it?  Are you trying to do two-way encryption between the app and the server?  Encryption can be a nasty beast to tame if you don't know exactly what you're doing and why.

Comment: If your app needs to store (user) data securely, I recommend using the "EncryptedSharedPreferences": https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data. Kindly edit your question and give a better description what your app does to need encryption.

Comment: I second all the comments above.  The answer to "How can I decrypt a string if I encrypt it with a random key?" is: you need the key.  If you don't have the key because it was randomly generated and not stored somewhere, you cannot decrypt it.

Comment: You should post some code of what you tried, and what used a "random key".

Answer (score 0):

As you have already discovered, a random key doesn't make sense for your app. Instead, you want to derive a key from the master password. To that end, you use a *key derivation function* or *KDF*.

In order to prevent dictionary attacks, you must also use a salt. A salt is a random value that you generate once and then store in your app (without any encryption).

**Create salt**

```
void initSalt()
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
    
    ... save salt ...
}
```

**Get key for encryption**

```
SecretKey getSecretKey(String masterPassword)
{
    byte[] salt = ... retrieve saved salt ...

    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    char[] chars = password.toCharArray();
    int hashIterations = 1024;
    int keySizeBytes = 32;
    return keyFactory.generateSecret(
        new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, hashIterations, keySizeBytes * 8));
}
```

The *getSecretKey()* function is call both when the password manager is first setup as well as on any later use. The function will always return the same secret key if the salt doesn't change.

Some Android versions might not support *PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256*. If so, you have to revert to *PBKDF2withHmacSHA1*.

With the secret key generated from the master password, you can then go ahead an encrypt the data that the password manager wants to store.